# How to create application level variable in node.js

Tags: node.js, cron, npm

In my project I have running more than 100 cron jon using npm [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron). My problem is I need to stop any cron job at run time.

my code is 
in app.js file

```
var cronJobRunner =require('cronJobHandle.js');
global.jobManager = {};
cronJobRunner.startServiceFromCronJobManager("service 1")
```

in cronJobHandle.js

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
    module.exports = { 
        startServiceFromCronJobManager: function (scheduleServiceName) {


           var serviceList =['service1','service2','service3','service4']
          serviceList.forEach(function(service){

           var job = new CronJob('* * * * * *', function(){
                        console.log("Service running");

                      }, function () {
                            // This function is executed when the job stops
                      },
                       true /* Start the job right now */,
                       timeZone /* Time zone of this job. */
                    );
             global.jobManager.service = job;
         });

        },
        stopServiceFromCronJobManager: function (scheduleServiceName) {
             console.log(global.jobManager); 
             global.jobManager[scheduleServiceName].stop();
        }
    };
```

router.js

```
var cronJobRunner =require('cronJobHandle.js');
app.route('/stopservice',function(req,res){
     cronJobRunner.stopServiceFromCronJobManager("service1");
}
```

When I call http://localhost:9999/stopservice
I am getting undefine in console.log(global.jobManager);

Please help me how to maintain cron jobManager variable comman for all server side js files

Answer (score 2):

It **is** global but there's two bugs in your code.

1) you're calling the property called `"service"` instead of the one whose name is in `service`.

Change

```
global.jobManager.service = job;
```

to

```
global.jobManager[service] = job;
```

2) you're pottentially using `global.jobManager` in cronJobHandle.js before to declare it in app.js

There's a better solution. you don't need and should use `global`. Just declare a standard variable in cronJobHandle.js instead (so that it isn't accessed by other modules):

```
var jobManager = {};
...
jobManager[service] = job;
...
jobManager[scheduleServiceName].stop();
```

Comment: after change you code also I getting undefine when  I am  consoling conole.log(global.jobManager);

Comment: I am using cluster to run my application in different instance, becauses of this I get the error